# In Play 2 how to check if a JsValue variable is NULL?

Tags: json, scala, playframework

This question may smell stupid but I really want to know how to check a NULL JsValue in Play 2:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json._

scala> val json = Json.obj("a" -> true)
json: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"a":true}

scala> val a = json \ "nonExisting"
a: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = null

scala> a == null
res1: Boolean = false

scala> Option(a)
res2: Option[play.api.libs.json.JsValue] = Some(null)
```

You can see the value of the variable `a` is `null` but the `==` check returns with `false`. However the below works as expected:

```
scala> val b: JsValue = null
b: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = null

scala> b == null
res3: Boolean = true
```

And when I turned to type conversion with `asOpt`, it seems work again:

```
scala> val c = json \ "a"
c: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = true

scala> c.asOpt[Boolean]
res4: Option[Boolean] = Some(true)

scala> a.asOpt[Boolean]
res5: Option[Boolean] = None
```

Comment: For me, the case you have above did not work; I had to use the second solution to compare your equivalent of `b == JsNull` instead of `b == null`.  `b` of type  `play.api.libs.json.JsValue = null` gave me `false` for `b == null`, but `true` for `b == JsNull`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you tried the same operation in JavaScript with actual JSON, normally you'd get `undefined` not `null`. This is represented by `JsUndefined` not `JsNull`. You can look for this instead:

```
a.isInstanceOf[JsUndefined]
```

or through using pattern matching:

```
a match { case _: JsUndefined => true; case _ => false })
```

How cool is that Scala's strong typing, accurately reflecting the JSON behaviour!? :)

Comment: Does that really work? I get the following warning during compilation when testing if `myJsValue.isInstanceOf[JsUndefined]`: `fruitless type test: a value of type play.api.libs.json.JsValue cannot also be a play.api.libs.json.JsUndefined`

Comment: Doesn't work. `val jsValue: JsValue = JsNull; Logger.info("jsValue.isInstanceOf[JsUndefined]: " + jsValue.isInstanceOf[JsUndefined])` --> displays `false`

Comment: @Blackbird That is because null != undefined.

Comment: @Blackbird Google for the SO question: What is the difference between null and undefined in JavaScript?

Comment: Ok, I must have misunderstood. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 5):

Check for equality with [`play.api.libs.json.JsNull`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsNull$):

```
if (a == JsNull) { ... }
```

or

```
a match {
  case JsNull => ...
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. `a == JsNull` returns `false`.

Comment: This worked for me, after it was mapped to options, but I was dealing with a slightly different problem.  For me, the lookup result was `res32: play.api.libs.json.JsLookupResult = JsDefined(null)` for an object `dataValue`.  But this seemed to work: `dataValue.toOption.get == JsNull` returned `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best/safest way to do this is to take advantage of Options:

```
val a = (json \ "nonExisting").asOpt[Boolean] // Or whatever type you might expect
if (a.isEmpty) {
  println("json does not contain key: nonExisting")
} else {
  println("nonExisting value: ${a.get}")
}
```